# How to use VB web client to sign into a website, using POST or other. i.e. Facebook

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, post, webclient

I have a function that pulls and formats the source code of pages using a the VB *webclient*. I need a way to pull the source code of the page as though I were signed in on a browser.

I understand that I could use *httpwebrequest* in normal circumstances but this doesn't yield even the normal page, but one saying the browser is out of date. Even when I have used a new *useragent*. I believe it is related to the browser the request uses in VB.

I have been trying to do this using POST requests with the *webclient* but this doesn't work either. Below is the closest I have got.

```
    Dim url As String = "URL HERE"
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim s As String
    Using client As New Net.WebClient
        Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
        reqparm.Add("email", "EMAIL HERE")
        reqparm.Add("pass", "PASSWORD HERE")
        client.Headers("user-agent") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
        Dim responseBytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm)
        Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responseBytes)
        s = responsebody
    End Using

    I then proceed to output it to the next section of the program.
```

The attempt above just returns the normal source code. I'm guessing I'm completely missing how this works and how to implement it.

TL;DR:
Need to use vb *webclient* to pull source code of a page whilst acting like its signed in, but *httpswebrequest* is not an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to log in facebook, you should use their API. It allow you to access all information you need in a good format.

Comment: And scraping their pages or using any such automated tools is explicitly against Facebook ToS.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, I'll take a look at both of those.
The only reason I have tried to tackle the problem like this as I wanted to apply the same function to other sites, Facebook was just what I was trialling this on.